# Discount on certain payment methods in Magento

Tags: magento

I am trying to make our payment methods give an extra 5% off when checking out. We have 3 methods to choose from but only 2 want to give the discount.

Yes - Bank Transfer
Yes - Phone Payment
No  - Purchase Order

For some reason the discount is only showing on Bank Transfer and not Phone payment if I select this option in checkout.

Could someone please look at my settings and tell me what I am doing wrong?

Link: [Conditions](http://www.bigdecsltd.co.uk/media/infortis/_home/slideshow/Screen2.jpg)

Link: [Actions](http://www.bigdecsltd.co.uk/media/infortis/_home/slideshow/Screen3.jpg)

Thanks! :)

Comment: can you just do the "If Payment Option" "IS NOT" PO. I don't think you need to do all three.  If you have more than what is listed (like Visa/MC) are you wanting to discount those? in other words i think you are being redundant on the conditions. Does that make sense?

Comment: If you mean take away all the "IS" payment options so there is only the "IS NOT" on the purchase order I get the discount showing on purchase order & bank transfer, but not the phone payment.... confusing! :(

Answer (score 0):

make sure is activated and date range is correct, sometimes it happens ;)

Comment: I have it activated so I can see the result in the cart and the date ranges are correct and within the time of testing, unfortunately I am totally lost in getting this to work! :(